# Determine new equation from a substitution

Tags: calculus

If $(1-x^2)y''-xy'+y=0$ and $x=\sin(t)$ determine the new equation.

Sorry if this question might seem somewhat incomplete.
All I can think to do is plug in $sin(t)$ in to $x$ but I am not sure what to do from there.

Comment: Simply plug it in and remember that $\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) =1$

Comment: @Amzoti I am assuming I would need to solve it. Once I plug in sin(t) is it correct to solve it as I would any ODE?

Comment: Yes, but recall, we currently have $dy/dx$ and when we substitute in $x$, we also need to change to $dy/dt$. Clear?

Comment: Yes. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, I actually wrote an answer, but forgot to do that last step too! :-) Regards